# JQGrid filterToolbar search inputs column merge

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using filterToolbar search inputs for each column inside my grid.

Is there a way to merge 2 search inputs into 1 input ?
(I'm filtering 2 columns together with the same value)

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used - Guriddo jqGrid or free-jqGrid? What is your datatype?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can set `colspan="2"` on the corresponding element (`<th>`) of the filter toolbar (`.ui-search-toolbar`) and to set `style="display:none"` on the next `<th>` element. The corresponding code could depend on the fork, which you use. For example

```js
var $toolbarElements = $($grid[0].grid.hDiv).find(".ui-search-toolbar").children("th");
var p = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam");

//$($toolbarElements[2]).attr("colspan", "2");
$($toolbarElements[p.iColByName.name]).attr("colspan", "2");

//$($toolbarElements[3]).hide();
$($toolbarElements[p.iColByName.note]).hide();
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/khm97Lsu/